# Distance weighted probability

Tags: probability, distance

I would like to know if what I want to calulate has probability of presence/absence is valid or not, and the best way to do it.

I have a collection of points, and each point has 5 neighbors. For each point I know the probability of presence as well as for the 5 neighbor points.

```
NPoint1
              NPoint2              NPoint3

                   |POINT|

    NPoint4

                           NPoint5
```

I would like to calculate a weighted presence probability for |POINT|, by taking into account the probability and distance of each NPoint as well as the |POINT| probability

Answer (score 1):

Your question as written is a bit circular: You stated that you already know the probability for |POINT| as well as its five neighbors. In that case, you have defined away your problem.

As a variant, which may be what you meant, is the case where you dont know the probability at |POINT|, only the probabilities at NPoints 1 - 5. In this case, there is a whole field devoted to this, its called [spatial interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_interpolation). This is used extensively in environmental engineering, hydrology, and mining. In your case, you are spatially interpolating *probability of presence*, instead of concentration or density etc.